# How to use JSONPath to return a full array filtered by its elements?

Tags: json, jsonpath

How to return a full array filtered by its elements using JSONPath?
It seems like when the current node `@` is an array the filter is acting on the array elements and not on the array.

e.g.
I want to return the array that its first element is `1`

```json
{
   "a": [1,2,3],
   "b": [4,5,6]
}
```

Query:

```
$.*[?(@[0]==1)]
```

Returns:

```json
[]
```

I would expect it to return

```json
[[1,2,3]]
```

While the following query:

```
$.*[?(@==1)]
```

Returns:

```json
[ 1 ]
```

I tried it with different JSONPath engines on https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ and didn't manage to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on https://jsonpath.com/:

```
$..[?(@[0] == 1)]
```

Comment: So why is this not working? 
$.*.[?(@[0] == 1)]

Comment: Is it because $.*. addresses each array while .. addresses the parent object first? JSONPath filter, when applied to an array, operates on each element of the array, an integer in this case.  JSON filter, when applied to an object, operates on each of its children, an array of integers in this case.

Comment: But this $.*.[?(@ == 1)] will return only 1 (not the array containing 1), so basically there is no way to return the array itself other then using $..[..] which will scan the entire json (which is not what we want...)?

Comment: You could avoid a deep scan by $[?(@[0] == 1)] This addresses the main object only and filters its children